# How to limit a bundle's use of services in OSGi?

Tags: java, osgi

I'm developing an OSGi platform, following the ideology of Pattern Extender.
There is a module called Kernel, which verifies the installation of the other modules, verifying the metadata in the Manifest.
This module presents a series of interfaces to other modules and also registered web services and other things for each of the modules.
What I want to know is whether it is possible to control the use of services such as HttpServices in dependent modules.
The Kernel, records Servlets and services in a particular url. *I like, that none of the modules that are part of the platform to use for example, the HttpService*. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you asking about the import of service API packages, i.e. using Import-Package? Or do you want to restrict the ability of certain bundles to bind to particular services?

Comment: @NeilBartlett yes, the idea is restrict the ability of certain bundles to bind to particular services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict the ability of a bundle to find a particular service, you can implement some service hooks. See http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/index.html?org/osgi/framework/hooks/service/package-summary.html

You will probably want to implement a FindHook to prevent the bundle from being able to locate the service in the service registry and also an EventListenerHook to prevent the bundle from receiving service events about the service. These two will prevent the bundle from normally obtaining the ServiceReference to the service which is necessary to bind to the service.

Comment: Worth mentioning perhaps that you can also use the Security layer of OSGi, by requiring bundles to hold a ServicePermission for a specific service interface. However this is more of a heavy-handed solution and requires the Java 2 security system to be enabled.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Thanks I will consider for the solution.